# fabric sed function not substituting string in python file

Tags: python, sed, fabric

I have the following function in my fabfile.py

```
def _update_settings(source_folder, site_name):
    settings_path = source_folder + '/superlists/settings.py'
    sed(settings_path, "DEBUG = True", "DEBUG = False")
    sed(settings_path, 'DOMAIN = "localhost"', 'DOMAIN = "%s"' % (site_name,))
```

After running the fabfile, with site_name set as `tdd.box.tk` I have the following output

```
DEBUG=False
DOMAIN='localhost'
```

Instead of

```
DEBUG=False
DOMAIN='tdd.box.tk'
```

DOMAIN doesn't change to the site_name variable passed.
I know the problem is with the string substitution path but cant figure it out

Answer (score 1):

I was able to figure out the solution. It turns out that in my settings.py I had

```
DOMAIN='localhost'
```

instead of

```
DOMAIN="localhost"
```

The string in the `sed` function must match exactly with the string in the file you are trying to substitute.

Comment: I was trying to replace the DEBUG settings in django settings.py file so it doesn't really matter with the spacing